# Google Sheets Query double group by for data

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I was wondering what the Excel or googlesheets function was for taking a set of data with two labels and aggregating it by one of them and transposing it for graphing would be.  To illustrate the problem, I have an image below:

[image]

I am interested in taking the 3 columns on the left and converting them to be viewed like the 3 columns on the right.

Comment: While Excel and Google Sheets have several functions that are the same there are several that are not. IMHO, including both apps makes the question too broad.

Comment: I know that the Google sheets query likely will yeild an answer that is simpler and that someone may know; however, excel is potentially more widely used, and while I expect a much dirtier answer if given by excel I will still use it.  I have done a lot of coding in other languages to get the data to export in a table and whatever converts it to this structure will work.  Ultimately either answer may also be helpful to the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer - it was using pivot and group by at the same time:

`=query(AR6:AT15,"select AS, avg(AT) group by AS pivot AR")`